# Too Many Redirects, intermittent issue - suspect Rewrite Cache

Tags: iis, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

Environment
Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit
IIS 8
Plesk 12.5

A website running WordPress responds intermittently with Too Many Redirects but only for specific URLs and only for approximately 30 minutes.  After that the requested page is served as expected.  The rest of the website responds correctly throughout that time using the same rewrite rules.

One URL in particular is affected more than others. It may be relevant to note that it is featured on the website home page and is being pushed through Social channels.

Failed Request Tracing shows the following for a particular URL:

URL_REWRITE_START RequestURL /category/referendum-2/

REDIRECT_FROM_CACHE_ACTION CachedRedirectedURL http:// www.website.com/category/referendum-2/ RedirectType Permanent

URL_REWRITE_END RequestURL http://www.website.com/category/referendum-2/

This obviously is the start of an infinite redirect loop.

When the URL is served correctly Failed Request Tracing shows:

URL_REWRITE_END RequestURL /index.php

This obviously correct for WordPress, /index.php handles all frontend page requests.

If a querystring is added to the requested URL eg. /category/referendum-2/?key=value IIS serves the requested page correctly.  Because of this I suspect the querystring causes IIS to skip the rewrite cache meaning the cache causes the redirect loop.

I've seen the post at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/danielvl/2010/01/07/registry-values-for-iis-url-rewrite/ detailing how to disable the rewrite cache via the registry but the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Rewrite does not exist. I'm not keen to create the key to see what happens in a production environment.

Can anyone suggest if my suspicions re. the rewrite cache being the cause of the redirect loop are correct?

If so how can I proceed to resolve the issue?  I'm struggling to find any detail about the redirect cache or what might cause behaviour like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by adding a condition to the redirect rule responsible for invoking the infinite redirect loop with a parameter that cannot be cached thus sidesteping the cache.

```html
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

Changed to

```html
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{REMOTE_PORT}" pattern=".*" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```

A better solution might be to update the frequentHitThreshold and frequentHitTimePeriod in applicationHost.config.  For details see http://www.ckode.dk/server-configuration/tuning-iis-7-for-static-content/